# Extending or inheriting from an EF 5 DbContext

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

Is there a way to extend a EF 5 DbContext to include additional columns or tables?

We have an application that has it's own schema, but when a customer asks for some custom feature, we can add fields or tables to his application.

Example:

```
Table 'Customers'

CustId
Name
Address
```

The customer asks for a 'Phone' field that is exclusive to his application so we add a column to the 'Customers' table.

Our base model contains a definition for CustId, Name and Address, but what about the 'Phone' field that is restricted to this particular client?

I was thinking about merging the 2 DbContext or making our customer's DbContext inherit from the base DbContext, but none of those 2 options seems to be possible.

Duplicating the base DbContext would be a huge pain since the application has more than 600 tables and we do not want to go through all the models to add a field when we modify our base application.

Any ideas?

Are there other ORMs that makes this possible?

Comment: For an entity you would like to add a property to you could derive an entity from the base entity and add the new property. Then you would probably have to configure this hierarchy in a derived context - have you tried something like this?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what your are suggesting?

Comment: I don't have an example - it was just a thought... If you have an entity A with the Id property and a context containing DbSet<A> in one assembly you would create an entity (in the new assbemly) B that derives from A and have a new property. In the new assembly you would create a context derived from the other context and configure that B is a derived from A (not sure if this is necessary but might be). I don't know if it will work but I don't see why it should not (EF supports inheritance) and also you should be able to verify this in 10-20 minutes.

Comment: Where would I tell EF where to find the new field? In my case I currently test with an EDMX. Should I go with Code-First?

Comment: Sorry, yes I was thinking about code first. Things are a bit more complicated if you use Edmx. I think you could try CodeFirst just to see if what I proposed above is feasible...

Comment: I managed to make this working in about 20 minutes with NHibernate. I guess Entity Framework might not be the best tool for the job in that case.